# How can I decode a QR from close up without increasing framingRect size?

Tags: java, android-camera, zxing, qr-code

My app, which uses ZXing to scan QR codes, can't read a QR Code unless the phone is VERY far away from the code (see picture, 6-7+ inches away and still not reading). The code is centered and well within the framingRect, but the camera seems to only be picking up result points from the top 2 positioning squares. I have increased the size of the framing rectangle through some code which I found here, which does yield a much better result.

Code: (replaces getFramingRect from zxing.camera.cameramanager.Java)

```
public Rect getFramingRect() {
    if (framingRect == null) {

        if (camera == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Point screenResolution = configManager.getScreenResolution();
        int width = screenResolution.x * 3 / 4;
        int height = screenResolution.y * 3 / 4;

        Log.v("Framing rect is : ", "width is "+width+"   and height is "+height);

        int leftOffset = (screenResolution.x - width) / 2;
        int topOffset = (screenResolution.y - height) / 2;

        framingRect = new Rect(leftOffset, topOffset, leftOffset + width, topOffset + height);

        Log.d(TAG, "Calculated framing rect: " + framingRect);
    }
    return framingRect;
}
```

For reasons beyond my comprehension, with this new larger framing rectangle, codes can be read as soon as they fit inside the rect width, whereas previously the code had to occupy a small region at the center of the rect (see pic).

My Question:
How can I make code scan as soon as it is within the bounds of the framing rect, without increasing the size of the rectangle? Why Is this happening?

[image: ZXing Trial Scan]

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width and height to 4/4 (just leave them as the screen resolution) and then change the framing rect visual representation to make it seem as if the scanner is only inside that. Worked for my app.